# What is the font used in this image?

Tags: font-identification

I'm having difficulty figuring out the font used in the text that is circled below. 
[image]

The person who sent me the image said this might be Georgia, but upon closer inspection and comparison, some of the characters (particularly upper and lower case "c") don't bear any resemblance to that font.

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE. Is this from a web page?  If the text is actual html text, and not part of a raster image, you could find the name of the font by inspecting the html and css. There are browser plugins which allow you to do that. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/884177/how-can-i-determine-what-font-a-browser-is-actually-using-to-render-some-text/20830300#20830300) for more info.

Comment: Hello, @BillyKerr. No, this is not from a webpage. I've already tried using browser plugins and websites to try and figure out the font, but to no avail.

Comment: These plugins will only work if the text is encoded in html/css. So that's why I asked.  They won't work on rasterized text. There's no text information in rasterized text, so the only way to find out what it is is to use your eye, or attempt automatic font recognition using various websites. Have you read [our help page](https://graphicdesign.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2366/89608) on how to ask font ID questions?  There are many links provided for automatic font recognition.

Answer (score 1):

The image you are providing is in such low quality that an automated font recognition is probably out the question:

[image]

It's a bit like searching for a person that looks like this:

[image]

There are probably millions of people who could fit that "description".

So you will have to some reverse engineering. Rewrite the text (or parts of it), place it on top of the image and go through all your fonts to find the best fit.

When I try that with the fonts I have activated right now, I can make many fonts fit more or less:

[image]

To me it seems like *Garamond Premier Pro* (or another Garamond) is very close although it's not a perfect match.

Comment: What if I enhanced the image with an image enhancement software?